# GWT 2.8.1 JsInterop is not workin

Tags: gwt, gwt-jsinterop

I am new to GWT, I am trying to implement sample program using JsInterop 
 but it does not work.

```
   JavaScript code:-

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Jsinterop.css">
    <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>
    <scripttype="text/javascript"language="javascript"src="jsinterop/jsinterop.nocache.js">


        var foo = new com.example.jsinterop.client.MyJsType();
        if (myType.aStaticMethd) {
        alert("Ask me what's the meaning of life...");
        }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </html>
    How can I get simple implementation to work? Is there something I'm missing? 
   ------------------------------------JAVA CODE----------------------------            
    Related detailed java code for above javaScript is:-
    @JsType
    public class MyJsType implements EntryPoint {
    A sample type to be accessed from javaScript.
    public MyJsType(){}

   some method
    public String aPublicMethod() {
    return "Hello ";
    }
    @JsMethod
    public static String aStaticMethd() {
    return "method call";
    }
   on moduleload method
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
     TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Window.alert("HIII");
    aStaticMethd();
    Window.alert("HELLOOOOOOO");
        }
    }
```

------------------------------------JAVA CODE-------------------------------
How can I get simple implementation to work? Is there something I'm missing?

I have given  two alert statement in java code
   Window.alert("HIII");
    aStaticMethd();
    Window.alert("HELLOOOOOOO");                                             between alert statement  I am calling the API astaticMethod() in javaScritp  :-

```
var foo = new com.example.jsinterop.client.MyJsType();
if (myType.aStaticMethd) {
    alert("Ask me what's the meaning of life...");
}

</script>
```

with alert statement but javascript alert statement is not executing                                  According to my requirement  I am trying to call java object  in javaScript.

Comment: Related java code:-

Comment: What error are you getting? How are you compiling (what flags are you passing, what linker are you using)?

Comment: I have given  two alert statement in java code    between to that i am calling the API astaticMethod(); in java script